# Add Values to Handlebar.js @index

Tags: javascript, html, handlebars.js

I am using Handlebar template.

I iterate through a list and use the @index to number the id's as follows

```
{{#each employees}} 
  <tr>
    <td id='dp{{@index}}'>{{this.dpval}}</td>
    <td id='genMet{{@index}}'>{{this.genMet}}</td>
    <td id='venMen{{@index}}'>{{this.venMen}}</td>
  <tr>
{{/each}}
```

The above section would run when the page gets loaded , After this I might get a new list via an Ajax call and run that list with the above template script again and append the html to the table generated when the page got loaded

Here I require that the @index should not start from 0 but instead from where the last @index ended

I am looking for something like {{@index}} + rowCount etc where rowCount is some number

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

I could do this like this

Register a Helper

```
  Handlebars.registerHelper('calc', function(count) { 
        return count + cnt; // where cnt will be calculated
   })
```

And call the function with

```
<td id='dp{{calc @index}}'>{{this.dpval}}</td>
```